# Getting stuck to initialize object

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, soap, wsdl

i generate a service WSDL in my Visual Studio 2013 ,here is a part of the code

```
public partial class company : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string nameField;

    private address[] addressesField;

    private department[] departmentsField;

    private long idField;

    private bool idFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("addresses", Order=1)]
    public address[] addresses {
        get {
            return this.addressesField;
        }
        set {
            this.addressesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("addresses");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("departments", Order=2)]
    public department[] departments {
        get {
            return this.departmentsField;
        }
        set {
            this.departmentsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("departments");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public long id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool idSpecified {
        get {
            return this.idFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.idFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("idSpecified");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

 public partial class address : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private location locationField;

    private string address1Field;

    private string zipCodeField;

    private string address_type_nameField;

    private string gps_latitudeField;

    private string gps_longitudeField;

    private string address_idField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public location location {
        get {
            return this.locationField;
        }
        set {
            this.locationField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("location");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("address", Order=1)]
    public string address1 {
        get {
            return this.address1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.address1Field = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("address1");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public string zipCode {
        get {
            return this.zipCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.zipCodeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("zipCode");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
    public string address_type_name {
        get {
            return this.address_type_nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.address_type_nameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("address_type_name");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=4)]
    public string gps_latitude {
        get {
            return this.gps_latitudeField;
        }
        set {
            this.gps_latitudeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("gps_latitude");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=5)]
    public string gps_longitude {
        get {
            return this.gps_longitudeField;
        }
        set {
            this.gps_longitudeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("gps_longitude");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string address_id {
        get {
            return this.address_idField;
        }
        set {
            this.address_idField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("address_id");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

then when  i want insert a new company name with  the code as follows :

```
 Service.service my_service = new Service.service();
        Service.service_insert_request my_insert_request = new Service.service_insert_request();

         my_insert_request.module_code = "MAIN_MODULE";
            my_insert_request.uuid = "b4ed2a5d-f259-4c09-9b1d-d8804dde1099";
            my_service.service_name = "MY SERVICE NAME";
            my_service.company = new Service.company();
            my_service.company.name = "MY COMPANY NAME";
            my_service.company.addresses[0] = new Service.address(); // here can not initialize the company.addresses ,give me error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}


            my_service.company.addresses[0].zipCode = "84000";
```

it give me an error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} ,kindly do you have any suggestion or idea to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to access the address index zero without initializing it first.

Try this:

```
 my_service.company.addresses = new address[10];
 my_service.company.addresses[0] = new Service.address();
```

or initialize it in constructor of company.